# Layout-файл android

Tags: android, android-layout

Здравствуйте, я начинающий программист и столкнулся с одной проблемой. Искал ответ в интернете но так и не нашел. Помогите пожалуйста.
Мне нужно сделать чтоб на разных разрешениях экранов например на 480х800 и на 720х1280 layout-файл например main.xml подгружался разный. Как это можно реализовать? 
Где то слышал что нужно в папке res создать какой то новый каталог.

Comment: Странно искал. На официальном сайте Android есть ответ. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
res/layout – по умолчанию
res/layout-small
res/layout-normal
res/layout-large
res/layout-xlarge
```

Можно ещё так:

```
res/layout-sw200dp
res/layout-sw600dp
res/layout-sw800dp
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Помогло

Comment: sw - smallest width