# Логика построения Android приложения в Rad Studio

Tags: android, android-layout

Какой тут аналог Layout-файлов? Что использовать, формы? Ведь можно было сделать так [Layout-файл android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/315994/layout-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-android)
В Rad Studio такой возможности не предусмотрено?